# Use of the definite article

Tags: grammar, articles

So I have been confused with the use of the definite article when I write.

Here is an example from one of the English tests

> Some people believe that there should be fixed punishments for each type of crime. Others, however, argue that `the circumstances of an individual crime`, and `the motivation for committing it`, should always be taken into account when deciding on `the punishments`.

Let me explain why this is confusing me. First, I think the article should not be used because those `circumstances` and `motivation` are general. it refers to circumstances of every individual crime. Those circumstances were not mentioned before and not unique. They can be any circumstances. Also, motivation does not sound unique either as well as `punishments`.

Why do they have the article? shouldn't they just be used without 'the'?

Comment: Are you confused because you think it should be `argue that *a* circumstance of an individual crime` or because you think it should be `argue that *circumstances* of an individual crime`?

Comment: I believe it should be 'circumstances of an individual crime' because it is meaning all circumstances

Comment: "punishments" s/b singular "punishment".  It is generally treated as uncounable, unlike "penalties". For example, one punishment could comprise several penalties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No!

You are talking about **the specific** circumstances of *any individual!*.

Don't we say that a man decides 'right' or 'wrong' things according to 'the circumstances/situation' he is passing through? *(ignore the facts of this sentence)*.

Here, an individual could be anyone, but then once we define that individual, we **then** talk about specific circumstances/situations he passes through.

We often say or advise someone...

> It all depends on **the** circumstances. You simply cannot resist it!

When we define any case's results, we try to be specific mentioning the 'circumstances'.

So, 'any individual' but 'the' circumstances he's in, are specific!

About 'motivation' and 'punishment' in this case, again, any crime committed by anyone, but there should be some **specific** motivation (negative?) and *the* punishment for that is also specific.

I think we have to take this entire paragraph in a way that we have an individual (any individual) but then, we are talking about 'specific' situations wherein he commits crime being motivated by some specific reasons and then gets punishment.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So If I wanted to say that circumstances should be considered in general then the sentence can be like the follow?
'Others, however, argue that circumstances, and motivation, should always be taken into account when deciding on punishments.'

Comment: Yup, *I think so*. Because here, you are general and not specifically talking about an individual's circumstances. In my own example, if I remove 'you simply cannot...' and want to make the sentence 'general', I'll say... it all depends on circumstances **without** mentioning anyone/you/me etc.

Answer (score 0):

If we read it without 'the' we get:

> Some people believe that there should be fixed punishments for each type of crime. Others, however, argue that circumstances of an individual crime, and motivation for committing it, should always be taken into account when deciding on punishments.

To me, this implies that there are more than one set of circumstances for an **individual** crime. Which isn't true. If the author had written:

> circumstances of individual crimes

it would make sense, whereas

> the circumstances of individual crimes

does too.

Motivation is similar, because the other refers to 'it', not 'them'.

I think it should be 'punishment' not the plural.