# Using definite article"the"?

Tags: definite-article

1)**Dog's presence** was a calming influence on patients.

2)**The dog's presence** was a calming influence on patients.

**The** should be used in this situation or not?
And i want to know why

Comment: Duplicate?https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53424/use-of-the-definite-article

Comment: If you want to speak about *this* dog's presence, yes, use "The" dog. If you want to speak about *any* dog's presence, use "A" dog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the article "The" here in this sentence, because you are referring to a dog, not someone or something named Dog.